# Store successful Stripe Payments in my MongoDB and validate it before serving products to user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, stripe-payments, atomic

I'm currently developing an e-commerce similar application using node js and MongoDB. It's not just an e-commerce, it's an application in which the user can accumulate points to exchange for products and services, so points can be earned and bought.

The entire system relies on two-phase commit protocols to ensure DB consistency, and when an error or prohibited action occurs, rollback actions are triggered to recover a consistency state.

My team have engineered the system using this approach so we can leverage MongoDB's speed in any scenario, making the application super fast and providing a better UX, with the help of a SPA built with Angular 5 + Angular Universal.

Now we are currently implementing the payment system, and we are trying to define the best way to process the payment, validate it and update our database accordingly, so the bought products/services can be granted to authorized users.

We are thinking about using Stripe to do so, by creating the token client side and storing it in user's cart before charging it, so we can keep track of unsuccessful payments and the respective actions to be taken in each case.

We've thought about the following cart schema:

```
{
    _id: USER'S MONGODB ID,
    items: [
        {
            _id: ITEM'S MONGODB ID,
            unitaryPrice: Number,
            quantity: Number
        }
    ],
    totalPrice: Number,
    totalItems: Number,
    status: 'ACTIVE',
    paymentInfo: {
        creditCardAmount: Number (value to be paid in cash),
        paymentToken: String (stripe token received from client),
        fromUserBalance: Number (points used from user's balance: defined by user, if he/she wants to use points from their account and if balance is $gt 0 : creditCardAmount + fromUserBalance must be equal to totalPrice before proceeding to charge step)
    }
}
```

And this is the sequence that is going to happen:

- User add/remove items in cart
- User triggers checkout process, in which credit card info is sent to Stripe and a token is received
- Upon success, this token is sent to our node server and user cart is updated to:

  {
      status: 'WAITING_PAYMENT',
      paymentInfo: {
          paymentToken: STRIPE'S GENERATED TOKEN
      }
  }
- After this, user cannot edit the cart anymore until the payment process is finalized
- In the sequence, this same cart is retrieved and an attempt to charge Stripe's token is made
- Upon success, cart is updated to {status: 'PAYMENT_SUCCEEDED'}
- Upon error, the cart reverts to {status: 'ACTIVE' and the token is $unset}
- After success, this same cart is retrieved and a document is created in another collection named 'purchasehistory' in which document's _id is the stripe token, making it unique and preventing duplicate history documents for the same cart. In this document, all cart info is stored, and after that the cart is emptied.
- A subroutine is triggered in this purchase history for making all products available to the end's user

That's it, this is the mechanism we've thought about to make payments possible in our site.

Do you guys think this is a good approach? Is there any mistake or missing step in the process? Remembering that every single step happens recursively to guarantee data consistency by using two-phase commits and updating the documents only if they meet the required keys values for each step.

My preoccupation is that a system failure happens just after the stripe token is charged and my cart is not updated to {status: 'PAYMENT_SUCCEEDED'}. In a recovery process I'd have to charge it again, and I'd have to receive an answer telling me that that token was already successfully charged, so I can move to the next steps of my purchasing sequence. Does Stripe's SDK provide this? Can I check if a stripe token was successfully charged already?

Comment: Remember that good questions don't ask for opinion based answers. You might want to [edit] the question and revisit the subjective things you are asking. There is also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for the portion of the question where you are asking if anything was overlooked.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll do as you suggested!

Comment: well... what was the verdict?  What was the conclusion?  Post your final answer !